# Is it possible to show dialogflow CX conversation summary to live agent?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, dialogflow-cx, dialogflow-cx-dashboard

I have a workflow where the user will chat with bot, once it is transferred to live agent. I need to show the summary of the conversation between user and chat to the live agent using vertex ai (Gemini pro, Text bison).

Btw, I don't see any possibility to retrieve conversation history programmatically.

Need your ideas. Is it possible at first place??

I have created a cloud function to to summarise a chat. But I don't know how to pass the actual chat to the cloud function